# Image with max-width:100% not scaling within element with position:absolute

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am currently working on a responsive carousel jquery plugin. The carousel shows 3 images on desktop devices, 2 on tablets and 1 on mobile devices. The LI items are floated left to create a strip of content and carousel-container has overflow:hidden to hide the elements within the strip not currently on show.

On mobile devices (max-width:767px) only one LI is shown and I want the image within the LI to scale as the browser size decreases. This is not currently working and I believe this may be because the UL has position:absolute. I have tried moving the image out of the carousel and it then scales as expected so I'm assuming some of the CSS applied to the carousel is affecting the CSS of the image.

Any help would be great.

The carousel consists of the following HTML:

```
<div class="container carousel-container">
    <ul class="carousel row">
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/768/384/" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/768/384/" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/768/384/" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.carousel-container{
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}

.carousel-container .carousel {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.carousel-container .carousel .item {
    position:relative;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: max-width: 100%; scales image to its parents width, but here there is no declaration for the parents width so what's the width the image should stretch to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/LGJ5w/ where if you specify the width of the parent then

```
max-width: 100%;
```

works fine else it fails. Try to stretch the output iframe.

Comment: Just tried adding a width of 767px to all the LIs and it made no difference

Comment: Can you test again after removing display: block; from the images?

Comment: Yup tried and still not quite right. I could commit to Github for you to fork? Appreciate the help.

Comment: https://github.com/decodedcreative/_bootstrap3-project/tree/carousel-plugin-enquire